# Creating a PHPUnit mocked model uses default database instead of test in CakePHP

Tags: php, unit-testing, cakephp, mocking, phpunit

I am testing a model in CakePHP 2 and have mocked a model like this:

```
$this->User = $this->getMock('User', array(
  '_saveUploadedFile',
  '_removeUploadedFile',
)); 
$this->User->expects($this->any())
        ->method('_saveUploadedFile')
        ->with($data, Configure::read('App.myDirectory'), true);
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
$this->User->expects($this->any())
        ->method('_removeUploadedFile')
        ->with($data, Configure::read('App.myDirectory'))
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));
```

Since any operation with the database raises the following error:

```
"Database table mock__user_b6241a4cs for model User was not found."
```

I redefined the model information:

```
$this->User->alias = 'User';
$this->User->useTable = 'users';
```

Now the test works well, but it's using the `$default` database in `database.php` instead of `$test`. What can be happening?

Why the database configuration for testing changes when using mocked objects? Could it be related to database permissions that causes the mocked object not being able to create its custom tables?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem by passing the correct parameters to the model constructor in `getMock()` third agument:

```
$this->User = $this->getMock('User',
  array('_saveUploadedFile', '_removeUploadedFile'),
  array(false, 'users', 'test')
);
```

Applying what is said in [Stubs section](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.stubs) of PHPUnit documentation, this third argument indicates that I want to use the `users` table and the `test` datasource.

I have to keep the redefinition of the `alias` property though:

```
$this->User->alias = 'User';
```

because a simple `$this->User->read(null, 1)` raises an error saying that `'User.a_column'` couldn't be found.

Thanks to [José Lorenzo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/684965/jose-lorenzo).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this specific problem before, but I'm curious if you've tried setting the specific connection you want. So the same way you set `alias` and `useTable`:

```
$this->User->useDbConfig = 'test';
```